# Spring Security 6.0 allows me to see the h2-console login page but doesn't allow me to go inside, how do I do?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm struggling to access my h2-console under the protection of Spring Security 6.0, here is the code

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                .permitAll()
        )
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                .ignoringRequestMatchers("/h2-console/**"))
        .headers(headers -> headers
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin());
    return http.build();
}
```

I can see the h2-console login page though I'm not allowed to go inside.

[image]

similar code works well with Spring Security 5.7.5

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
    .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
            .permitAll()
    )
    .csrf(csrf -> csrf
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**"))
    .headers(headers -> headers
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin())
    ;
    return http.build();
}
```

I also tried `WebSecurityCustomizer`, which doesn't work either.

```
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring()
            .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**");
}
```

Here is the debug log

> Securing POST
> /h2-console/login.do?jsessionid=aa31e312f86f5a876457524984cad7e0
>
> Invalid CSRF token found for
> http://127.0.0.1:8080/h2-console/login.do?jsessionid=aa31e312f86f5a876457524984cad7e0
>
> Responding with 403 status code

What am I missing?

Comment: And your enabled spring security debug logs that tells you the exact reason is telling you?

Answer (score 1):

All the merits go to [this github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12546#issuecomment-1382891839).
I'm just copying the solution over here to make it more convenient to find, as I experienced myself various h2 console problems (401, 403, ...) when I migrated my app from spring boot 2.7.x to 3.0.x (e.g. spring core 5.x to 6.x, and spring security 5.x to 6.x), and it took a little while to fall on that actual github issue and find that solution, which works perfectly fine (more details on why the antMatcher is still being used can be found in the linked github issue...):

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                )
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions().disable())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                        .ignoringRequestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")));
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I traced the source codes from `CsrfFilter.java`, checked the comparison logic that happens inside. Only to find that it is comparing the provided ignoring URL `/h2-console/**` with the requesting URL,let's say it is `/h2-console/login.do`, from which the servlet name counterpart `/h2-console/` gets removed, therefore comparing `/h2-console/**` with `login.do` instead, end up being evaluated to false.

I dont know what the new purpose would be for doing this, but set CSRF disabled could fix this problem.
Or you could manually put a custom matching logic instead of telling Spring nothing but a URL pattern:

```
http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(new RequestMatcher() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String contextPath = request.getServletContext().getContextPath();
        return request.getRequestURI().startsWith(contextPath + "/h2-console/");
    }
});
```

I dont like lambda at all. I will update this answer if I know something new.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable csrf, frameOptions, and allow path through requestMatcher to make it all work. I also used *toH2Console* as it automatically provides correct matcher.

```
import static org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest.toH2Console;

@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(toH2Console())
                .permitAll()
...
```